# MySQL DELETE failing randomly and very infrequently

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, insert

I have a MySQL `DELETE` statement followed by an `INSERT` statement to ensure only one copy of a data set for a given ID. (There is a reason why I do not use UPDATE)

The problem is that I have noticed in a data set spanning 5000+ entries that there are 3 instances where the DELETE statement did not execute, but the INSERT statement did. The end result was duplicate entries for the given IDs.

Below is my code. On execution failure the php script will exit with an error message. It must be my level of experience. Any ideas what the problem could be?

```
//delete
$query_delete = "DELETE FROM q1_6_list WHERE q_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($q[qID])."'";   
$result = mysql_query($query_delete) or errorReport("Error in query: $query_delete. ".mysql_error());
//insert
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO q1_6_list (q_id, vehicle, quantity) VALUES";
$result = mysql_query($query_insert) or errorReport("Error in query: $query_insert. ".mysql_error());
if (!$result)
    errorReport($result);
```

**EDIT**

On closer inspection I noticed that I did not add the below code right after `$result = mysql_query($query_delete)....`

```
if (!$result)
    errorReport($result);
```

Could this also be required to catch all other error messages, or would `mysql_query($query_delete) or errorReport...` catch all error occurrences?

Comment: minor bug: `$q[qID]` should be `$q['qID']`. this can blow up spectacularly on your if you actually HAVE a constant named `qID` - php will treat undefined constants as an unquoted string when in array key context, but if the constant exists... boom. As well, what exactly is the error message? Don't leave us hanging...

Comment: @MarcB I wish those were `E_ERROR` instead of `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: Actually there is no error message I could trace. It is returned to the users application. I also do not see anything in error_log.txt for that line of code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not have a UNIQUE constraint on the table?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to create a primary key on q1_6_list (q_id):

```
ALTER TABLE q1_6_list ADD PRIMARY KEY(q_id)
```

and use MySQLs `REPLACE INTO` syntax, so lose your delete and your insert becomes:

```
$query_insert = "REPLACE INTO q1_6_list (q_id, vehicle, quantity) VALUES";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run insert query only if delete query was successful:

```
if (mysql_query($query_delete)) {
    mysql_query($query_insert);
}
```